# How do I get radio station name on Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the radio station name from Android. I am trying to get the current radio station name. I have receivers for the radio, but I really don't know how to get the names of the playing station.

Comment: station names dont keep changing rapidly. So, locally map the station names with the frequencies. But, you should be maintaining your application to add the support for future radio stations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. FM Radio is [not part of SDK](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6332). If you are lucky, you may try vendor specific SDK if it exists (quite unlikely, unfortunately) or try to check if radio of your interest is not supported by some of [3rd party tools](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=497977).